# how to add return none if element not found in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

respond_timestamp=[]
for i in range(17,18):
    print(i)
    try:
        url='https://www.darooyab.ir/doctor/9/دکتر-شهرام-مظاهری?page='+str(i)
        #print(url)
        response = requests.get(url).content.decode()
    except:
        continue
        
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser') 
    comment= soup.select('div.comment')
    #print( len(comment))
    
    for rt in [i for i in soup.select('div.comment')]:
        try:
            for out in [j.text for j in rt.select('div:nth-child(3) > span:nth-child(1) > label:nth-child(1)')]:
            #print(rt[1])
                pattern=r'دکتر شهرام مظاهری - متخصص قلب و عروق'
                respond_timestamp.append(re.sub(pattern,'',out)) 
        except:
            respond_timestamp.append(None)
            
print(len(respond_timestamp))
```

I want to append `respond_timestamp` to the list. the returned value for `respond_timestamp` may be empty, then I use `try`/`except` and `append(None)`, But `None` doesn't add to the list. Because count of the list is important.

What should I do?

Comment: Whe you say that respond_timestamp could be empty, you mean respond_timestamp = '' or respond_timestamp = None?

Comment: you may get a great deal more from trapping and handling the Exceptions rather than throwing them away completely; `except Exception as ex:` .. then you can refer to `ex` in the scope of the `except` block (for example display it with `print(repr(ex))`, explicitly check its type, inspect its methods, etc.) - even the [Zen of Python (`import this`)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python) suggests _Errors should never pass silently._

Comment: I crawl question/answers from some sites and usually, some answers are empty, But questions exist, therefore I should write 'None' for attributes about the answer. finally I covert all lists to a JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** *Check/print your list, it is not the None that won't be appended, it is your "timestamp" that is missing in the end - Based on your example*

#### What happens?

1. Main issue is that `re` module is not imported (look at your example)
2. These not necessary list comprehension make the code very confusing and debugging harder. Also it will in case there is no `responseComment` not start your loop cause it is an empty list and this will make your `try` successful and won't lead to an exception.

#### How to fix?

Import `re` module to avoid exceptions and change your for loop - Select only one element to check in your `try`:

```
for rt in soup.select('div.comment'):
    try:
        out = rt.select_one('div:nth-child(3) > span:nth-child(1) > label:nth-child(1)').text
        pattern= 'دکتر شهرام مظاهری - متخصص قلب و عروق'
        respond_timestamp.append(re.sub(pattern,'',out)) 
    except Exception as ex:
        print(repr(ex))
        respond_timestamp.append(None)
```

#### Example

**Note** *if your goal is to generate dictionaries, do it along the process and not by zipping multiple lists,...*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = []
for i in range(17,18):
    try:
        url='https://www.darooyab.ir/doctor/9/دکتر-شهرام-مظاهری?page='+str(i)
        response = requests.get(url).content.decode()
    except:
        continue

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'lxml') 

    for c in soup.select('.comment'):
        # pattern=r'دکتر شهرام مظاهری - متخصص قلب و عروق'
        # print(re.sub(pattern,'',c.select_one('div:nth-child(3) > span:nth-child(1) > label:nth-child(1)').text)) 
        data.append({
            'commentDate':c.span.text.split(' ')[1][1:-1],
            'commentText':c.div.text,
            'responseDate':responseDate.text.split(' ')[-1][1:-1] if (responseDate := c.select_one('.responseComment label')) else None,
            'responseText':responseText.text if (responseText := c.select_one('.responseComment .commentText')) else None,
        })

data
```

#### Output

```
[{'commentDate': '1398/12/29',
  'commentText': 'سلام من برای الرژیم قرص کیتوتیفن مصرف  میکنم  و برای تنفسم هم خیلی عالیه احساس میکنم ریه هام باز میشه توی دم و باز دم . آیا توی این مدت که این بیماری کرونا اومده استفاده از این دارو رو مشکل ساز است؟\r\n',
  'responseDate': None,
  'responseText': None},
 {'commentDate': 'راهان',
  'commentText': 'با سلام خدمت جناب آقای دکتر. ببخشید من به عل داشتن گواتر قرص لووتیروکسین سدیم 1 مصرف می کنم و تا الان شش کیلو وزن کم کردم . ممکنه راهنماییبفرمایید چکار کنم تا کاهش وزنم متوقف بشه. سپاسگزارم ',
  'responseDate': '1399/2/25',
  'responseText': 'سلام مربوط به قلب نمی شود'},
 {'commentDate': '1398/12/28',
  'commentText': 'سلام . من دیروز به دلیل درد معده و اسهال بیش از حد به پزشک مراجعه کردم . برای من سیپروفلوکساسین و دیفنوکسیلات تجویز کردن . مصرف که میکنم اسید معدم میاد تو دهانم . میخواستم بدونم مشکل از دارو هست یا بنده م',
  'responseDate': '1399/2/25',
  'responseText': 'سلام مربوط به قلب نمی شود'},
...]
```